# Detect nodes of a curved grid using opencv

Tags: opencv

I have a few pictures of grid under TEM, I'm trying to get coordinates of the nodes(crosses) of the grid.

I tried to follow the tutorial of detecting sudoku grids or normal lines. I don't know if it is the reason of my lines are curved or the line is the same color as background. My result isn't very satisfying. Here's my code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread("test.png")
original = image.copy()
cv2.imshow("Image", image)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow("gray", gray)

blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
cv2.imshow("blur", blur)

ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 32, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
low_threshold = 50
high_threshold = 150
edges = cv2.Canny(thresh, low_threshold, high_threshold)

cv2.imshow("edges", edges)
rho = 1  # distance resolution in pixels of the Hough grid
theta = np.pi / 180  # angular resolution in radians of the Hough grid
threshold = 30  # minimum number of votes (intersections in Hough grid cell)
min_line_length = 50 # minimum number of pixels making up a line
max_line_gap = 250  # maximum gap in pixels between connectable line segments
line_image = np.copy(image) * 0  # creating a blank to draw lines on

# Run Hough on edge detected image
# Output "lines" is an array containing endpoints of detected line segments
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, rho, theta, threshold,
                        np.array([]), min_line_length, max_line_gap)
print(lines)
for line in lines:
    for x1,y1,x2,y2 in line:
        cv2.line(line_image,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(255,0,0),1)
cv2.imshow('result',line_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This is the picture of the grid.

[image]

After converted to gray scale, applied GaussianBlur and thresh holding.
[image]

The result of canny edge detection

[image]

Then, the final result after Hough Line transform

[image]

Comment: As you write yourself, those arent lines but curves. What do you expect from a line detection? Do you want segments? Also maybe try to segment the black parts between the green parts, since they are continuous.

Comment: @Micka I only want to get the coordinate of the crosses, so I thought the line detection could work. About your suggestion, could you tell me what kind of method I should use?

Comment: Is it possible to get the knowledges about the imaging system (location of principal point, image distortion, etc) in advance?
It may help you, even if it's not very accurate.
For example, if using them can modify the image shape to "more straightly", you may be able to detect "lines" more easily.

Comment: @XuanhaoWang Mask the region containing the mesh. Invert it such that the edges are in white and holes in black. Perform skeletonization and proceed